# Getting Errors while Creating DynamoDB table using SAM Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I want to create a DynamoDB table using SAM template and I am new to the SAM template.
I don't have a better idea of **Hash** and **Range**
Here is my DynamoDB template part

```
  MyDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: customerInformations
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: phoneNumber
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: firstName
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: lastName
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: address
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: email
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: phoneNumber
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: firstName
          KeyType: RANGE
        - AttributeName: lastName
          KeyType: RANGE
        - AttributeName: address
          KeyType: RANGE
        - AttributeName: email
          KeyType: RANGE
```

Here is the Error Code I am getting while Creating a table.

```
CREATE_FAILED       AWS::DynamoDB::Table        MyDynamoDBTable             Resource handler retur                                                               message: "1 validation
error detected: Value '[K
eySchemaElement(attribute
Name=phoneNumber,
keyType=HASH), KeySchemaE
lement(attributeName=firs
tName, keyType=RANGE), Ke
ySchemaElement(attributeN
ame=lastName,
keyType=RANGE), KeySchema
Element(attributeName=add
ress, keyType=RANGE), Key
SchemaElement(attributeNa
me=email,
keyType=RANGE)]' at
'keySchema' failed to
satisfy constraint:
Member must have length
less than or equal to 2
(Service: DynamoDb,
Status Code: 400, Request
ID: 2SRKQ9ETQUEGIC6GO0HHT
70JIJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9A
SUAAJG)" (RequestToken: b
9b143a9-c010-f185-4811-93
a3b91f2e52,
HandlerErrorCode:
InvalidRequest)
```

Any Help would be highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a table with 4 Range keys. Dynamo only supports one Partition and one Range key. You should take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) before continuing.

Example solution:

```
  MyDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: customerInformations
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: phoneNumber
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: firstName
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: phoneNumber
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: firstName
          KeyType: RANGE
```

Comment: Yes, I understand now that I have added multiple Range keys.  But what is the solution?
If I remove all the Range Key except one, then I get this error.
`Resource handler returned
   message: "Number of
  attributes in KeySchema
  does not exactly match
  number of attributes
  defined in
 AttributeDefinitions"
 (RequestToken: 0b1433dc-1
 fa6-7502-f481-fc41164f99c
7, HandlerErrorCode:
InvalidRequest)
`
I have tried many ways but got different errors without any success.

Comment: You also need to remove the keys from the AttributeDefinitions.